Chebyshev Subdomains
The following piece of code creates a grid subdivided into equally spaced Chebyshev subdomains as well as the corresponding differentiation matrix. In this example, we have four subdomains, each with twenty points.
pnx = 4;
npx = 20;
nx = 1 + pnx  (npx - 1);
xbnd = {0, 1};
xdata = Table[(xbnd[[2]] - xbnd[[1]])/(1 + 
        pnx + (pnx - 1)  Cos[\[Pi]/npx])  (Cos[(\[Pi]  j)/npx] - 
       1), {j, 0, npx}] // N;
xgrid = ConstantArray[0, {nx + 1}];
xgrid[[1]] = xbnd[[2]];
Do[xgrid[[(pp - 1)  (npx - 1) + ii]] = 
   xgrid[[(pp - 1)  (npx - 1) + 1]] + xdata[[ii]];, {pp, 1, pnx}, {ii,
   2, npx}]
xgrid[[-1]] = xbnd[[1]];

a = Table[
   Product[If[j == k, 1, (xdata[[j]] - xdata[[k]])], {k, 1, 
     npx + 1}], {j, 1, npx + 1}];
D1xP = Table[
   If[i == j, 
    Sum[If[k == j, 0, 1/(xdata[[j]] - xdata[[k]])], {k, 1, npx + 1}], 
    a[[i]]/(a[[j]]  (xdata[[i]] - xdata[[j]]))], {i, 1, npx + 1}, {j, 
    1, npx + 1}];
Clear[a]

D1xN = Table[0, {i, 1, nx + 1}, {j, 1, nx + 1}];
Do[D1xN[[1, kk]] = D1xP[[1, kk]];, {kk, 1, npx + 1}];
Do[D1xN[[(ii - 1)  (npx - 1) + jj, (ii - 1)  (npx - 1) + kk]] = 
    D1xP[[jj, kk]];, {ii, 1, pnx}, {jj, 2, npx}, {kk, 1, npx + 1}];
Do[D1xN[[nx + 1, nx + 1 - npx - 1 + kk]] = D1xP[[npx + 1, kk]];, {kk, 
   1, npx + 1}];

I would like to generalise the above code to one where I can control where the subdomains start and end. Hopefully, I would also like the specify the number of points in each of the subdomains.
